# No route matches "/error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var" with {:method=>:get} while uploading 2.2 gb of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am running apache(2.2.11) as frontend server to mongrel and using rails application trying to upload 2.2 gb of data but i am getting

route matches "/error/HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY.html.var" with {:method=>:get}
 error

anyone has any idea to deal with it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache probably has a restriction on the upload size, resulting in a redirect to an error page that isn't handled by apache itself but by your rails app.

Is there a **LimitRequestBody** somewhere in your apache config?

Comment: no nowhere ,there is no LimitRequestBody in my httpd.conf file

Comment: nd when am tryiing to upload 2.2 gb of stream with apache 1.3.33 ,i am getting invalid content length error ,so move to apache 2.2.11 version.

Comment: but in php.ini file i have one parameter